# Include layout in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

My `master.blade.php` file is like below

```
<body>
    @include('layouts.header')
    @yield('content')
    @include('layouts.footer')
    @include('layouts.footer-script')
</body>
```

My `dashboard.blade.php` file is like below

```
@extends('layouts.master')

// I would like to add Menu here

@section('content')

//more code here

@endsection
```

My `menu.blade.php` is like below.

```
@extends('dashboard')

@section('menu')

// more HTML code
@endsection
```

How can I add `Menu` in `dashboard.blade.php` ?

Answer (score 0):

`dashboard.blade.php` file is like below

```
 @extends('layouts.master')
    
    
    @include('menu')
    
    @section('content')
    
    //more code here
    
    @endsection
```

`menu.blade.php` is like below.

```
 <div>
    
    // more HTML code
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your menu is static just use it as include

dashboard file

```
    @extends('layouts.master')
    @section('content')
    @include('layouts.menu')
    @endsection
```

and menu file will be (menu.blade.php)

```
  <a href=''>Home</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

master.blade.php

```
<body>
  @include('layouts.header')
  @yield('content')
  @include('layouts.footer')
  @include('layouts.footer-script')
</body>
```

dashboard.blade.php

```
    @extends('layouts.master')
    @include('menu')
    @section('content')
    //more code here
    @endsection
```

This is your code.
It is Good.
If this is error, I think the path must have been wrong of menu.blade.php.

ex:@include(frontend.menu)

Thank you for your answer.